arithmetic function to return an integer from lower "L" up to maximum "M", from any integer input
I'm trying to create a function (using only addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, modulus, and maybe exponentiation, roots and logarithms) to return an integer from lower "L" up to maximum "M", from any integer input "X".
For clarification, this function must obey 3 rules:

if X is lower than L, return L.
if X is higher than M, return M.
if X is equal to M or L, or any number in between, return X.

All these variables are integers (Z).
Example: let's suppose L = 0 and M = 3, then
f(-4) = 0 (rule 1)
f(-3) = 0 (rule 1)
f(-2) = 0 (rule 1)
f(-1) = 0 (rule 1)
f(0) = 0 (rule 3)
f(1) = 1 (rule 3)
f(2) = 2 (rule 3)
f(3) = 3 (rule 3)
f(4) = 3 (rule 2)
f(5) = 3 (rule 2)
f(6) = 3 (rule 2)
etc.

Is it possible to create an expression like that without using logical operators?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There are lots of ways.  You have $M-L+1$ possible outputs, so take $\bmod (M-L+1)$ and add $L$

For clarity: you want an expression (in the variables $x, L, M$) for a function $f_{L,M}(x)$ such that for all $x$, $f_{L,M}(x) \in [L,M]$.  What you have written allows that you might want (or at least allow) a different expression (in the variable $x$) for each choice of $M$ and $L$.

As written, you do not require the function to be surjective, so $L$ is a fine function.  I presume you do not like that option, but it indicates that you probably have some objectives for the function that you have not specified.

Are you allowing yourself the use of the min(imum) and max(imum) functions? What about absolute value?

\begin{equation*}
f(X) = \frac{1}{2}\Bigl(|X-L|-|X-M|+M+L\Bigr)
\end{equation*}
Note that $|x|$ can be written as $\sqrt{x^2}$, so this fits your criteria.
